# MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable; trying to use <class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'> instead

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

Is there any way to use moving plot without ffmpeg?

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_barchart, frames=range(1968, 2019))
HTML(animator.to_jshtml()) 
animator.save('dynamic_images.mp4')
```

My code is above, I am getting the key error`.mp4'`,  `ValueError: unknown file extension: .mp4`

I tried installing `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg` end up with SSL issue

- Is there any way to use moving plot without ffmpeg
- As like error throwing is there any way to use 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'

Disclaimer : I went through the link `https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows` but the URL is blocked by the IT team

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save animated plot as `.gif` with use of [`celluloid`](https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/)  library:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera
import numpy as np


# create figure object
fig = plt.figure()
# load axis box
ax = plt.axes()
# set axis limit
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

camera = Camera(fig)
for i in range(10):
    ax.scatter(i, np.random.random())
    plt.pause(0.1)
    camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate()
animation.save('animation.gif', writer='PillowWriter', fps=2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: MovieWriter PillowWriter unavailable; trying to use <class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'> instead.

Comment: @Nons yep i con't find solution for this notification

Comment: Got the same error message as @Nons . DId you manage to find a solution @Nons?

Answer (score 14):

This is my frist answer on SO, so please be gentle.
The answer above seems like a good idea but it doesn't answer why the matplotlib built-in method doesn't work, so I decided to add some explanation.

This might be a duplicate ([possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316397/matplotlib-animation-no-moviewriters-available/40155317)).
The issue is that you're missing ffmpeg.
If you are using conda as your manager then install the missing packages.
You could also do that using apt, dnf, pacman or whatever else you are using.

In case you're using conda:
`conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`
[ffmpeg on anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg)

Probably you're going to miss another dependency, namely `Openh264`.
Again if using conda:
`conda install -c conda-forge openh264`
[Openh264 on anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openh264)

If you're still missing more dependencies, resolving them will depend on the platform you are using.
If you are using Windows I would recommend trying miniconda out.

In my case, after installing openh264 using conda (my platform was/is Fedora) I still encountered problems because the installed lib was called `libopenh264.so.6` instead of `libopenh264.so.5`.
I decided to try it out anyway and created a symbolic link to the version ending with `6` in the same directory (`/lib64/`) and it worked.